# dafny how to bound set comprehension resolver?

Tags: set, dafny

Trying to write an algorithm involving paths from a root of a binary tree to a leaf. I ran into the following error for the ghost var I was trying to define. I had intended to try to show that some other path was in this set. How do I resolve this error?

> the result of a set comprehension must be finite, but Dafny's
> heuristics can't figure out how to produce a bounded set of values for
> 'px'Resolver

```
datatype TreeNode = Nil | Cons(val: nat, left: TreeNode, right: TreeNode)

predicate isPath(paths: seq<TreeNode>, root: TreeNode) 
    requires root != Nil && root == paths[0] ==> root !in paths[1..]
{
    if |paths| == 0 then false else match paths[0] {
        case Nil => false
        case Cons(val, left, right) => if |paths| == 1 then root == paths[0] else root == paths[0] && (isPath(paths[1..], left) || isPath(paths[1..], right))
    }
}

method Test(root: TreeNode) {
   ghost var ps := set px: seq<TreeNode> | isPath(px, root) ;
}
```

I thought that perhaps Dafny implied that there could be a loop in the tree which would result in infinite paths, so I wrote the following to try to assert it was not possible. However, it still did not resolve the issue. I believe there should be a finite albeit large number of paths.

```
function TreeSet(root: TreeNode): set<TreeNode> {
    match root {
        case Nil => {}
        case Cons(val, left, right) => TreeSet(left)+{root}+TreeSet(right)
    }
}

function ChildSet(root: TreeNode): set<TreeNode> {
    match root {
        case Nil => {}
        case Cons(val, left, right) => {left}+ChildSet(left)+{right}+ChildSet(right)
    }
}

method Test(root: TreeNode) 
    requires forall node :: node in TreeSet(root) ==> node !in ChildSet(node)
{
   ghost var ps := set px: seq<TreeNode> | isPath(px, root) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dafny enforces finiteness of set using syntactic scan and fixed set of heuristics, as a result it is not exhaustive. Following example give same error

```
predicate test(i: int)
{
   i >= 10 && i <= 20
}

method Test(){
  ghost var s := set i | test(i);
}
```

Also no language construct exists to convince dafny that set constructed using set comprehension is finite set.

[1] https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/13#issuecomment-286909795

[2] https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/1366#issuecomment-906785889

Comment: This is because, until recently, heuristics were the only way to find the finite collection on which to iterate, and then use the predicate as a filter. However, you can get rid of heuristics if you use `iset`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the end of the story.

You can definitely use `iset` that don't have the constraint to check that they are finite.

The following code snippet works, modulo the fact that there are still unsatisfied preconditions in the recursive calls to `isPath`:

```
datatype TreeNode = Nil | Cons(val: nat, left: TreeNode, right: TreeNode)

predicate isPath(paths: seq<TreeNode>, root: TreeNode) 
    requires root != Nil && root == paths[0] ==> root !in paths[1..]
{
    if |paths| == 0 then false else match paths[0] {
        case Nil => false
        case Cons(val, left, right) => if |paths| == 1 then root == paths[0] else root == paths[0] && (isPath(paths[1..], left) || isPath(paths[1..], right))
    }
}

method Test(root: TreeNode) {
   ghost var ps := iset px: seq<TreeNode> | |px| > 0 && root != Nil && root == px[0] ==> root !in px[1..] && isPath(px, root) ;
}
```